# How to pull text from a Div on an external page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, external

On my page I have a ticker that I would like to load text into from my div on an external page. What I am trying to do is have the titles from articles that I have on a separate page be loaded into the ticker, I already understand how to load them to my ticker but I need to know how to pull the text from the external div (and load it within another div).

my external page

`<div id="boundry2"> <h5> <div class="title"> Title: </div> <div class="date"> Date </div> </h5> Article text <br/> </div>`

my ticker

`<a href="#"> <div id="myhtmlticker" class="tickerstyle"> <div class="messagediv"> Text from title </div> <div class="messagediv">Text from title </div> </div> </a>`

my ticker references an external Javascript code by the id that makes each div with the class messagediv appear. I want the text from `<div class="title">Title:</div>` on the external page to be loaded onto `<div class="messagediv">Text from title</div>`. keep in mind that there will be multiple articles and I want each title to show.
All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you would be glad to put your source code up, why haven't you already? ;) Source code is what this site works on. (Please provide a *minimum* sample though.)

Comment: Is this "external page" on the same domain as the original page with javascript code?

Comment: I have revised it, condensing my code as much as I could, and yes they are on the same domain.

Comment: If a visual representation is needed then here is [my page](http://astoriaband.webs.com/index.html) the ticker is up top by the navigation, and if you click on the news link it will bring you to the page that I would like to get the 'titles' from. P.s. sorry it doesn't look great, it's still testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. Use ajax request in the ticker to get the external page as the response text and then parse the response to find the title and then you can load it in your ticker.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFile(fileName, method, callback) {
    // you can also add xdomain request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, fileName, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                callback(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
}

function setTitle(response) {
    var result = response.match(/(<div class="title">(.*?)<\/div>)+/ig);
    var target = document.getElementsByClassName('messagediv');
    for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        target[i].innerHTML = result[0];
    }
}

getFile('testpage.html', 'get', setTitle);
```